# WooCommerce - How to disable another attribute if one attribute has been selected

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need help regarding the WooCommerce plugin. I want to achieve something like this but I don’t know how to do it

I want to have two attributes which are Color and Color Special Order. The customer can choose the color, or they can make a custom order color.

If they choose Color, they can’t choose Color Special Order. If they choose Color Special Order, they can’t choose Color. In conclusion, only one attribute can be selected.

Do you have any idea how to achieve this? I have tried to find plugins but none of them can achieve this. I have also bought WooCommerce Product Add-Ons but still can’t achieve this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variable product with the colors "red", "green", "yellow" and "custom", so the user can only choose one.

Now, you only need a field popping up when the user chooses "custom". For this, you can use a plugin (e.g. this one: https://pluginrepublic.com/custom-fields-for-woocommerce-variations/), maybe WooCommerce Product Add-Ons can add a field to a variation, too, not sure about that.

Comment: Thank you so much! WooCommerce Product Add-Ons can add a field to a variation but it can't add-on for a specific variation of a variable product